# (Done) Reopen request - How to negotiate an offer if I'm not actually going to accept it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[How to negotiate an offer if I'm not actually going to accept it](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/147902/how-to-negotiate-an-offer-if-im-not-actually-going-to-accept-it)

This was closed as too broad, but there is arguably a straightforward and answerable question in bold:

> **So should I try negotiation in this case, and what should be my strategy?**

Also, the question had already attracted several quality answers, closing it doesn't seem to make sense. I have voted to reopen and would like others to if they agree.

Comment: no idea why it was closed vtro, one more needed

Comment: I already voted to reopen this question. It's got 7 answers so far. That seems to imply that at least 7 people didn't find the question "too broad".

Answer (score 2):

Casted the fifth and final vote, and now the post is open again.